# How do I "unzoom" the currently selected character in Windows Character Map?

Tags: windows-10, character-map

When I launch the Windows character map, it looks like this:

[image: character map default view]

When I click on a character to select it, it looks like this:

[image: character map selected view]

Notice that the zoomed in view of the ± character obscures the ° to the left and the ² to the right.

So how do I get it to unzoom, so that the selected character is not obscuring the two cells next to it? I've tried hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

**EDIT**: I did figure out that if you double-click on the selected character, it puts the character in the "Characters to copy" text field and unzooms. I can use this, but I would still like a way to unzoom or deselect the current character without copying it to that field.

Comment: How did you get a black title bar?

Comment: @Kroltan Open `control.exe` from Win+R, then use the Desktop (non-Metro) Personalisation menu. Navigating through the right combination of menus will bring up the original Personalisation dialog (dating back to at least Windows 98!) from which you can change _everything_.

Comment: You're a hero! I always thought that dialog only applied to the classic theme (which was the case up to win7).

Comment: You can also get the same effect by going into the Metro settings app, going to the colors section, and setting the accent color manually. Then, on the same page, enable "Show color on title bar" to get that color to show up on window title bars.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### How do I get it to unzoom (without adding the character to "Characters to copy")?

Press <kbd>space</kbd> (Switch between Enlarged and Normal mode when a character is selected).

> ```
> RIGHT ARROW Move to the right or to the beginning of the next line
> LEFT ARROW  Move to the left or to the end of the previous line
> UP ARROW    Move up one row
> DOWN ARROW  Move down one row
> PAGE UP     Move up one screen at a time
> PAGE DOWN   Move down one screen at a time
> HOME        Move to the beginning of the line
> END         Move to the end of the line
> CTRL+HOME   Move to the first character
> CTRL+END    Move to the last character
> SPACEBAR    Switch between Enlarged and Normal mode when a character is selected
> ```

Source [Windows XP Character Map Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.shortcutmania.com/Windows-XP-Character-Map-Keyboard-Shortcuts-printable-cheatsheet.htm)

Comment: What an intuitive UI...

Comment: @Muzer: and great the way this help appears when I strike F5 or click `Help`, or would be great if it did appear or at least appear in the “frequently” asked questions.

Comment: @Muzer What do you mean?  As soon as you get frustrated and start banging your fists on the keyboard, that's the most likely key to get struck.  It's so intuitive you can do it without even trying.  ;-)